Update to the Discrete Matrix Riccati Equation in Kalman Filter
We know we can pre-compute the asymptotic gain of Kalman Filter through the Matrix Riccati equation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Asymptotic_form
$$\mathbf{P}_\infty = \mathbf{F}\left(\mathbf{P}_\infty - \mathbf{P}_\infty \mathbf{H}^\textsf{T} \left(\mathbf{H}\mathbf{P}_\infty\mathbf{H}^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{R}\right) ^{-1} \mathbf{H}\mathbf{P}_\infty\right) \mathbf{F}^\textsf{T} + \mathbf{Q}.$$
$$\mathbf{K}_\infty = \mathbf{P}_\infty \mathbf{H}^\textsf{T} \left( \mathbf{R} + \mathbf{H} \mathbf{P}_\infty \mathbf{H}^\textsf{T} \right) ^{-1}.$$
My understanding is that there is no analytical solution to the matrix form. We just have to iterate until $P_{\infty}$ converge then solve for $K_{\infty}$
This equation seems to assume that $R$ doesn't change. However is there a way we can update the solution to $K_{\infty}$ when $R$ changes with cheap computational cost? My $R$ is diagonal. If we do know $P_{\infty}$, then $K_{\infty}$ is trivial to update with woodbury identity given $R$ is diagonal.  But obviously changes to $R$ would affect $P_{\infty}$ too. So not sure if there is a cheap way...
In addition to $R$ being diagonal, my $F$ is identity if that makes solving the equation easier..

Are you asking about when $R$ varies with time? Namely one would then have to use the normal Kalman filter updates and immediately using the new steady state value does not guarantee stability of the filter.
